# You are not logged in: You are not logged in. Please log in and try again

Tags: codeigniter, hybridauth

I am using HybridAuth library in my codeigniter application. but when i click on login with facebook button it gives error "You are not logged in: You are not logged in. Please log in and try again.". Please help some to know why this error occured.

Answer (score 1):

This error is due to wrong 'Valid OAuth redirect Url' in Facebook login product settings. I also gone through this error. Facebook came up with Facebook Login product that links to a facebook app. Please check below correct settings pics i have that i got working -

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

Answer (score 0):

FB login was working just fine but i think after Facebook Platform APIs updates 
my issue was adding http**s** to the Redirect URL

http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html

should be :

https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html